# What does browser.Stop() does differently from browser.StopLoad() in CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp

I want to stop the browser and all its activity like rendering, loading resource requests, etc. so I need to know what browser.Stop() does apart from browser.StopLoad() in CefSharp

Comment: `CefSharp` is just one of many `Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)` wrappers. `Stop` calls the upstream `API`. https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/docs/118.6/classCefBrowser.html#a560c886c908980a98d0522c2512d6a7f

Unfortunately there isn't much information about what it actually does, you can look at the source on https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef or ask on https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php